# Using strip_tags with custom exclusion

Tags: php, regex, strip-tags

In my code I need so strip all tags from a string excluding tag with inline "display:none" attribute, so tags like this:

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

should stay intact.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Is there any way I can make strip_tags work this way?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm asking "What would be the best way to achieve this?" because I don't know if there is some easy way to do this, I'm not very good in regex to code this so I will have to write a manual logic if there isn't any easy way do do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it like:

$div = preg_replace('/<(?!/?div style="display:none)[^>]+>/','',$div);

Answer (score 1):

You can pass second parameters (want to exclude)  to strip_tags as like

```
   $str =  "<html><div style='display:none'></div></html>";
   echo strip_tags($str,  '<div></div>');
```

Output will be `<div style='display:none'></div>`

Comment: But I need other divs which doesn't have display:none attribute removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex  **/<[^>]*>/**

```
    <?PHP 
$val = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', '<div style="display:none">tessss</div>') ; 
echo $val ;
?>
```

strip_tags only work on visible tags but regex is the best way

Comment: I think you got the question wrong, I meant that all tags EXCEPT <div style="display:none"></div> should be removed